# iOS - single select in Kal calendar

Tags: xcode, ios8, kal

i face little problem with [kal calendar library](https://github.com/phaibin/Kal), I cant use single selection , when I select a day the next day is selected , i need single select without offset

here is the problem

[image]

here is the code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
//#define Single
#ifdef Single
    kal = [[KalViewController alloc] initWithSelectionMode:KalSelectionModeSingle];
    kal.selectedDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[[NSDate date] offsetDay:1]];
#else
    kal = [[KalViewController alloc] initWithSelectionMode:KalSelectionModeRange];
    kal.beginDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[NSDate date]];
    kal.endDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[[NSDate date] offsetDay:1]];
#endif
```

what i have been tried

1- I set  `offsetDay:1`  To `offsetDay:0` then delete it in  KalSelectionModeSingle mode 
but its still the same

2- comment KalSelectionModeRange mode

```
   //kal = [[KalViewController alloc] initWithSelectionMode:KalSelectionModeRange];
   //kal.beginDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[NSDate date]];
   //kal.endDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[[NSDate date] offsetDay:1]];
```

i get white window with no data

any help

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure the answer simply get my code out

```
//#define Single
#ifdef Single
    kal = [[KalViewController alloc] initWithSelectionMode:KalSelectionModeSingle];
    kal.selectedDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[[NSDate date] offsetDay:1]];
#else
    kal = [[KalViewController alloc] initWithSelectionMode:KalSelectionModeRange];
    kal.beginDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[NSDate date]];
    kal.endDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[[NSDate date] offsetDay:1]];
#endif
```

To

```
 kal = [[KalViewController alloc] initWithSelectionMode:KalSelectionModeSingle];
    kal.selectedDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[[NSDate date] offsetDay:1]];
```